# How to get label tag in html from django form

Tags: django

```
{% for field in columnMetaData %}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Code above only displays `<input>...</input>`

But how to get and `<label></label>`, because labels exists in  `columnMetaData`

I forgot to say that columnMetaData is `ModelForm`

### NEW UPDATE

Just another question. Is there way to add class in each `{{field}}` ?
And field to be like this: `<input type="" class="something" ></input>`

Comment: The way to go is using crispy forms http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ . Styling forms is notoriously boring and extremely verbose, and this library aims at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) to set classes for your field. Usage: `field=forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'some-class'})`

Answer (score 0):

Like that :

```
{% for field in columnMetaData %}
    {{ field.name.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show me your `columnMetaData`.

Comment: `<tr><th><label for="id_integerPolje1">IntegerPolje1:</label></th><td><input id="id_integerPolje1" name="integerPolje1" type="text" /></td></tr>`

Comment: With field.label i get just label not and <label> tag

Comment: Solved! `{{field.label_tag}}`. Now to see if it's possible to add class to field...